# Twitter streaming API para NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de obtener los tweets de una cuenta sea mía o de alguien mas.

Cree una cuenta en twitter, y cree una aplicación, tengo los token y las keys, quisiera saber si alguien ha utilizado esta API, debido a que quiero obtener el ultimo tweet publicado.

De igual forma si alguien sabe otra forma se lo agradecería, encontré esto, pero quisiera saber si hay que usar el require, o usar express o algo al respecto debido a que debe ser con nodejs.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para utilizar el paquete *[twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter)*, deberás:

Agregar la dependencia en el archivo `package.json`, la forma mas fácil es: (dentro de la carpeta del proyecto)

```
npm --save install twitter
```

Luego debes importar el modulo a tu aplicación y configurarlo con las claves que tienes. Por cierto, para eso sirve `require`, para importar otro modulo al modulo actual.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var twclient = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '', // debes poner los datos correctos en estos campos
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});
```

Todo esto como sabes esta en la documentación, ahora:

### Para obtener el último Twit

Debes obtener la ruta [`statuses/user_timeline`](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwik1pad7vXKAhWFGpAKHQsKBCAQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Frest%2Freference%2Fget%2Fstatuses%2Fuser_timeline&usg=AFQjCNFs5SMhCeDeqhmTHBGRFc27XIzXCw&bvm=bv.114195076,d.Y2I). Fijate en la documentación pues hay otras opciones para la consulta, aquí prepare una muy simple:

```
// preparamos los datos del usuario a consultar
var usuario = {
       // en screen_name, pones el nombre de usuario sin la arroba.
       screen_name: 'pedromiguelpimienta', 
       // la cantidad de mensajes a obtener
       count: 1,
       // solo mensajes propios (no re-tweets) 
       include_rts: false
}; 

twclient.get('statuses/user_timeline', usuario, function(error, tweets, response){
  if(error) throw error; // se produjo un error, manejar aquí

  if (tweets.length) {
     console.log(tweets[0].text);  // el texto del ultimo twit, si hay alguno
  }
});
```

Por cierto esta es una librería muy popular, solo hoy recibio mas de 1000 descargas.

#### EDICIÓN:

En este repositorio, te dejo un ejemplo funcional con las instrucciones para que puedas probarlo.

https://github.com/rnrneverdies/nodetwitter

Comment: Gracias @rnrneverdies, quisiera preguntarte algo, para usar de manera mas amena esto es mejor usar instalaciones por manager de dependencias de node osea **npm**, o puedo descargar la libreria desde su repositorio y copiarla a lo antiguo

Comment: De nada! Usar `npm` te da la ventaja (o desventaja, depende de ti) de no tener que adjuntar la librería con tu código. Es decir que luego cuando instales tu aplicación en otra maquina, solo corres `npm install` y el manejador de paquetes (npm) descarga en ese momento las dependencias y tu aplicacion ya esta lista para funcionar. Es una cuestión de orden.

Comment: gracias, tienes algun tutorial o algo por el estilo para entender como instalar y como usarla, la pregunta tambien seria, cuando use phonegap build para compilar y obtener la apk, tendrá problema alguno, o funcionara correctamente

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales habria que ver como esta armado el build, te sugiero que formules otra pregunta y expongas lo que tienes hecho y las dudas, así tendrás una respuesta completa y precisa. Por los comentarios, no se bien por donde empezar.

Comment: Ok, deja ya mismo la formulo, y me respondes asi me ayudas y te pongo como mejor respuesta, dame un momento

Comment: No me deja descargar por ningun modo usando d cualquier manera me aparece esto:

twitter@1.2.5

si lo descargo usando netbeans sale un error con muchas ventanas emergentes

Comment: no se como tienes armado el proyecto, si me das algo de tiempo, contestare tu otra pregunta, con ambas respuestas, veremos que pasa.

Comment: mira, fijate la otra respuesta para armar tu proyecto, te ayudara. por cierto esto no lo habia probado antes, lo escribí de memoria, pero acabo de probarlo y funciona muy bien.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, el brackets no me reconoce la carpeta de modules cuando la descargo con npm no se por q pero ok

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales buen día, siempre puedes formular una pregunta sobre un problema especifico ;)

Comment: ok gracias voy a formularla a ver si se puede solucionar

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales fijate que ahi puse un ejemplo de como puedes, usando node, usar esta funcionalidad combiando Ajax y la api de twitter.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Funciona perfecto, voy a tratar de hacerlo de manera streaming