# Como obtener siempre el ultimo tweet

Tags: php, nodejs, api, twitter-api

Quisiera saber como obtengo siempre el ultimo tweet de una cuenta especifica, no precisamente de la mía.

Ya he logrado hacerlo pero de forma estática, osea, utilizando node y de manera local, realizo hago una petición y obtengo la cantidad de tweets que en ese momento solicite.

Mediante esta forma, logro obtener el ultimo tweet pero utilizando refresh o pulsando un botón para actualizar la pagina.

Dejo este enlace por aquí [api twiter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4156/twitter-streaming-api-para-nodejs), es una pregunta que realice hace tiempo

Comment: Hola Pedro,  estas tratando de hacer esto en PHP,  nodejs o Javascript lado cliente?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz la idea es hacerlo del lado del servidor sea php o node, pero cualquier ayuda no importa el lenguaje me serviria

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "de manera streaming"? No termino de comprender qué es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, osea de manera que cuando el usuario publique algo nuevo pues me llegue la notificacion y el json por medio de la API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haciendo un script php que corra mediante cron cada X tiempo, cosa que cada X minutos consulte a twitter y actualice tus Bases de datos con el tweet del usuario.
Luego, en la página donde muestras el tweet, lo saque desde tu BD y no directamente de twitter. Espero explicarme.

Comment: Claro que si entiendo, lo que buscaba era, o mas bien pensaba que existía un api que lo hiciera pero veo que si toca hacerlo gracias, voy a tener que recurrir a este metodo

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales vale! pensé que necesitabas solamente tener el tweet, no conectarte directo a la api de streaming.  Mira, [http://mikepultz.com/2012/01/how-to-mine-twitter-streams-from-php-in-real-time](encontré esto), soluciona tu problema según entiendo. De todas formas, veo que no tienes problemas en hacerlo con node, por lo que te recomendaría verlo con node, ya que su naturaleza hace que hagas un proceso que corra indefinidadamente. En PHP, deberías dejar corriendo en un `while(true) { <proceso de extracción>}` como en el link que dejé

Comment: No, la idea es siempre tener el ultimo tweet y pues la idea es que si podia hacerlo mediante streaming, pero podria decirse, que tu solucion es buena

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales ah claro! para lo que necesitas, sería una solución muy compleja, para algo que es más simple (o se ve así). Tu problema sería solucionado totalmente si existieran notificaciones push en twitter, pero ellos no poseen esa solución. Ese tipo de solución sería aplicable usando IFTTT por ejemplo. Mira esto https://ifttt.com/channels/twitter/triggers/28-new-tweet-by-a-specific-user . Si esta "nueva" solución que te indico te funciona mejor, avisame y reescribo la respuesta en base a eso ;)

Comment: Ah no sabia que también se podría hacer eso con esa aplicación, ya la conocía, pero una pregunta, puedo obtener eso en forma de servicio, pues la idea es obtener el texto de tweet o la descripción como quieras llamarla, la fecha, la hora de un usuario especifico, si eso lo hace pues eso es mas que necesario.

Comment: Como sale en la documentación @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales, te entrega el texto del tweet, el usuario, el link, fecha de creación y el blockquote para llegar y agregar. mira este link http://stefanroth.net/2016/02/21/azure-automation-twitter-ifttt-webhook-start-runbook/ y este https://ifttt.com/maker bastaría hacer una receta que para tu funcionase para tu caso particular :)

Comment: tengo una duda, en el caso de IFTTT, podria usar la receta como un servicio API, osea que obtenga eso mediante una peticion GET?

Comment: No, justamente lo contrario. Si creas una receta como la que te indiqué, será IFTTT quien te notificará cuando el usuario en cuestión publique un tweet, por lo que tu solamente debes programar el endpoint donde IFTTT hará el POST del tweet

Comment: mmm, hablaba de una petición GET, debido a que lo ideal según la documentación de peticiones, si sera solo obtención de datos, pues usando el **Method : 'GET'** seria lo indicado, pero después que funcione entonces mas que suficiente me ahorro, todo ese trabajo de usar servidor y todo eso

Comment: En Python lo puedes obtener asi  --- lastTweet = api.user_timeline("cnn")[0]   --, espero te sirva este tips.