# API Twitter MEAN stream Node, Mongo y Angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, twitter

He instalado recientemente un NPM de Twitter en node, lo cierto es que funciona bastante bien, y realiza las tareas de la API corretamente, pero, en consola, ahora viene el momento donde quiero almacenar y mostrar más tarde en ángular en un formato que vaya apareciendo los mensajes en directo.

Para ello he revisado la información del post: [Twitter streaming API para NodeJs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4156/twitter-streaming-api-para-nodejs) Y como os comento funciona muy bien en consola.

La documentación que estoy utilizando es la siguiente: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html

El código que utilizo para que se vea correctamente en la consola es el siguiente:

```
client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: '@el_pais'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(event) {
console.log(event && event.text);
  });

  stream.on('error', function(error) {
    throw error;
  });
});
```

Y el código en el cual estoy trabajando es el siguiente:

```
twitterperfilesCtrl.streamPerfiles = async(req, res) =>{
  const twitterPerfiles = await twitterPerfil.find();
  const contadorPerfiles = await twitterPerfil.countDocuments();

  for( var i = 0; i < contadorPerfiles; i++) {
      if(twitterPerfiles[i].id){
        var track = { screen_name: twitterPerfiles[i].screen_name };
        client.stream('statuses/filter', {track}, function(stream) {
          stream.on('data', function(event) {
            console.log(event && event.text);
          });

          stream.on('error', function(error) {
            throw error;
          });
        });
      }
  }
  res.json(event.text);
}
```

Con mi código lo que pretendo es que recorra todos los perfiles que tengo para que se almacenen todos los mensajes que se publican de cada perfil y a su vez posteriormente se publiquen en ángular.

El problema con el que me encuentro es que con este código me aparece un error de **Status Code: 406** entiendo que este código aparece por que el formato en el que se está devolviendo los datos no es el correcto, eso es lo que entiendo pero no sé si realmente van por ahí los tiros.

El error que muestra:

```
events.js:173
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Status Code: 406
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\...\Proyectos personales\Project\node_modules\twitter\lib\twitter.js:277:28)
at Request.emit (events.js:197:13)
at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\...\Proyectos personales\Project\node_modules\request\request.js:1066:10)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:197:13)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:560:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:113:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:447:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\...\Proyectos personales\irisFMProject\node_modules\twitter\lib\twitter.js:277:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:197:13)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
```

Comment: Creo que el problema no está aquí, sino en la llamada AJAX en sí. ¿Dónde usas la función `streamPerfiles`?

Comment: Ha esa funcion desde un fichero de ruta hago una llamada GET